# Node.js "module "os" not found from"

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am running a Derby app. I am trying to use the plugin "nodemailer", but when it "require('os')", I get the error "module "os" not found from".[image]

What could be causing it?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to `require('os')` with browserify, which doesn't make sense. I don't know a lot about derby, but assuming it's something like meteor, you are probably trying to use `nodemailer` in client-side code.

Comment: Wonderful! Just put it in the server file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was requiring it in a file that was rendered on the client in a method similar to browserify. I just instead had to put it in "server.js", and call it from a server-side express route.